# Linking for both 32 bit and 64 bit DLLs

Tags: c++, dll

I have Some DLLs for both 32bit and 64bit system, The DLLs have the same name for both versions.

How can I link my c++ project to those DLLs

I do the following for linking:

From solution explorer in visual studio, right click on project -> properties ->
Linker -> Input -> put the name of .Lib files

I do the same steps for all configurations, The linking worked perfectly for 32bit, but did not for 64bit.

Comment: Are you using automatic linking or explicit call to LoadLibrary() from your code? Wha li

Comment: "but did not" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: I am using automatic linking as I explain

Comment: They can't have the same name and be in the same location... Why not link to the file with the full path?